# Accessing account balance in Bank System application

Tags: java

I am currently trying to create a simple bank program in which users can create an account, deposit and withdraw money. The problem is that I am having trouble with creating accounts.

Here is my main:

```
Account account = new Account();
account.createAccount(1000, "Bob");
```

Here is my Account.java class:

```
public void createAccount(int bal, String name){

    int balance = bal;

    String username = name;

    System.out.println("An account has been set up for "+name+", with a balance of $"+bal+".");
```

The problem I'm having is accessing the accounts which are created.
The account is created and the string runs, but I am not sure how I would be able to access the account.

I want to add a method in which you can call the account's balance but am not sure how to do this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The variables should be `fields` not local variables.  Unless you are dealing in Yen, then I guess that a balance should be something other than `int`

Comment: As per @ScaryWombat, use BigDecimal for dollar currency, as double/fields are not advisable for currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't showing much of your `Account` class (which is fine -- having a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is good, but a fully compilable code snippet would be preferable), so my answer will go with some assumptions:

1. You need to be able to retrieve and set the balance.
2. You don't currently have a solution for this problem.

I'll assume your current class looks like this (eliminating whitespace for brevity):

```
public class Account {
    public void createAccount(int bal, String name) {
        int balance = bal;
        String username = name;
        System.out.println("An account has been set up for "+name+", with a balance of $"+bal+".");
    }
}
```

As @ScaryWombat pointed out in his comment, you need to move the `balance` and `username` variables out of the `createAccount` method and into the class as fields. You then set these fields in the `createAccount` method:

```
public class Account {
    private int balance = bal;
    private String username = name;
    public void createAccount(int bal, String name) {
        this.balance = bal;
        this.username = name;
        System.out.println("An account has been set up for "+name+", with a balance of $"+bal+".");
    }
}
```

Now, an `Account` instance holds a balance and a name, which is overwritten when you call `createAccount`.

However, we still have a problem. Every time you call `createAccount`, the data is overwritten. For example in this code, Bob's account will be forgotten and the data overwritten by Alice's account:

```
Account account = new Account();
account.createAccount(1000, "Bob");
account.createAccount(2000, "Alice");
```

This is where constructors come in. Instead of a `createAccount` method, we'll move the logic into the `Account` constructor:

```
public class Account {
    private int balance = bal;
    private String username = name;
    public Account(int bal, String name) {
        this.balance = bal;
        this.username = name;
        System.out.println("An account has been set up for "+name+", with a balance of $"+bal+".");
    }
}
```

With this, the only way to create an account is to specify the starting details in the call to `new Account()`:

```
Account bobsAccount = new Account(1000, "Bob");
Account alicesAccount = new Account(2000, "Alice");
```

However, we still haven't addressed the core of your question: How to access the balance? The following will result in an error:

```
bobsAccount.balance = 2000;
```

This is because the `balance` field is private (as it should be). What we need is to add accessor methods to the `Account` class:

```
public class Account{
...
    public void setBalance(int newBalance) {
        balance = newBalance;
        System.out.println(name+"'s account balance is now $"+bal+".");
    }
    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
...
}
```

You might ask "why go to this trouble?", well, we can add checks (e.g. not allow a balance to go below zero), add logging to audit access to balances, or even not have a `setBalance` or `getBalance`, but only `transferFrom(Account otherAccount)` and `transferTo(Account otherAccount)` (ensuring money is never added, but only transferred around in the system).

PS. and as pointed out in other comments, `int` is never good for monetery amounts. What you need is a `Currency` type that uses something else, e.g. `BigDecimal`, to store the actual values.

Comment: This is a decent enough answer, but from a security point of view, the general advice is to not use string concatenation, instead using String.format. Ideally use logging over System.out too. E.g:         
System.out.println(String.format("An account has been set up for %s, with a balance of $%d.", name, bal));